# android 6.0.1 SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

В андроид 6.0.1 новое поведение пермишенна SYSTEM_ALER_WINDOW, если у пользователя установлен Google Play версии 6.0.5 или выше, то автоматически включается пермишен SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW (если он нужен).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an/36019034

---

Не понимаю какие изменения нужно сделать в коде, чтобы пермишенн включался автоматически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного неправильно поняли. В ответе английским по белому написано, что данный `permission` автоматически предоставляется, когда Вы ставите приложение из маркета версии 6.0.5 и выше. В противном случае нет. И пример кода.